# Visio 2016 : change effective default font?

Tags: fonts, themes, microsoft-visio, default-settings

I found a [MS doc page](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/When-I-change-the-font-Visio-doesn-t-use-the-new-font-in-my-shapes-23b27421-e063-4bf4-b69f-28ef0a33e868) for Visio 2007 that precisely expresses my problem:

> When I change the font, Visio doesn't use the new font in my shapes
>
> Symptoms
>
> When you change the font in the Text dialog box or in the Text list on the Formatting toolbar, the new font is not applied to unselected shapes or to  shapes that you subsequently place on the page.

This doc page gives step-by-step instructions for how to resolve, *in Visio 2007*. I can't seem to work out how to apply the version 2007 steps in Visio 2016, if indeed they can be applied?

I'm not finding any relevant updated documentation since then. The latest MS community forum is for Visio 2010.

Any assistance greatly appreciated, please. Thank you for your consideration.

Comment: I can't seem to figure out how to edit themes at all in the 2016 version.  Kind of infuriating.

Comment: Theming changed in 2013, but I'm not sure that it was fundamentally different in terms of what that document's suggesting.  Can you describe what behaviour you'd like to see?